# How can I allow sites to set custom protocol handlers?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, microsoft, mailto

in firefox it's easy to handle but ms edge? There is a problem, that you can't automatically open mailto links INSIDE ms edge with gmail. I tried following:

in the newest microsoft edge (also chromium browsers like google chrome) it's under settings => cookies and site permissions => protocol handlers or in german einstellungen => cookies und websiteberechtigungen => protokollhandler

is there a better way?

Comment: yeah i did it! just switch to edge in windows 10 settings => standard-apps => mail => edge and under settings => cookies and site permissions => protocol handlers you will see gmail under handler for e-mail links or in german einstellungen => cookies und websiteberechtigungen => protokollhandler => handler für e-mail links (mail.google.com standard)

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. Please note that SE sites aren't discussion forums. I'd suggest taking the [Tour](https://superuser.com/tour) and checking (at least) Asking and Answering -sections in the [Help](https://superuser.com/help) to learn about how the sites work. These are Q&A sites. Since you've resolved your issue, you should [write an answer](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer), then after 48 hours drop back to [accept](https://superuser.com/help/accepted-answer) it. You'll find also advice on [how to formulate a good answer](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer) in the Help.

Comment: @user371780 turn that comment into an answer in order to help others with the same question.

Comment: i can not can @music2myear

Comment: What do you mean when you say you cannot? You can answer your own question, you also do not need reputation to post an answer.

Comment: imgur.com/a/B5bzbbO